# Vue - global variables / common variable for two components

Tags: vue.js

Just started to learn Vue 3. 
I have 2 components that don't connect to each other (not child, not parent) 
I want to create variable that first and second component are able to change and according to it's value - display or hide content. 
Is it possible and where I need to create it.

Comment: it's possible, but please show what have you tried so far

Comment: If you know that you will have several cases where you'd need to share data between unrelated components, I suggest using [VueX](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/). It's a state manager on a global level.

Comment: Thank you, just figured out how Vuex work - and found solution with state.